# What do compile and link line refer to?

Tags: compiling, environment-variables, gcc, linker

While installing the cudnn library, I came across this in the `INSTALL.txt` file:

> Add [installpath] to your build and link process by adding
>   -I[installpath] to your compile
>       line and -L[installpath] -lcudnn to your link line.

What does compile and link line mean? Do I do this, while compiling `myFile.c` which uses cudnn:

```
gcc myFile.c -L /path/to/library -l /name/of/library
```

Or something else?

PS: They have also mentioned to do this:

```
cd <installpath>
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=`pwd`:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

But won't I need to write this out to my `.bashrc` file so that the environment variable is set every time my machine runs?

Answer (score 3):

Your `gcc` command combines the compile and link phase, so you need to add all the options given:

```
gcc -Iincludepath myFile.c -Llibpath -lcudnn
```

replacing `includepath` and `libpath` as appropriate.

And yes, you’ll probably want to edit your `.bashrc` to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=libpath:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

replacing `libpath` as appropriate.

`includepath` needs to point to the headers (`.h` files), `libpath` to the library (`.so`).

Answer (score 0):

Compiling and linking are the 2 major steps in the creation of an executable. Both can be  done with the `gcc` command. There is also a preprocessing step (before compilation) and an assembly (after compilation); these are almost always done at the same time as compiling so the combination "preprocess then compile then assemble" are treated as a single step called "compiling" for short.

The steps performed by a particular `gcc` command line can be determined as follows:

Write down the order "preprocess, compile, assemble, link".

If the input file is named `*.i`, remove the preprocess step (`.i` files are already preprocessed).

If the input file is named `*.s`, remove the preprocess and compile steps (`.s` files are already compiled).

If the input file is named `*.o`, remove the preprocess, compile, and assemble steps (`.o` files are assembled).

If there's a `-x` option, use it instead of the name of the input file in the preceding steps. (This is rare)

If the `-c` option is used, remove the link step.

If the `-S` option is used, remove the assemble and link steps.

If the `-E` option is used, remove the compile, assemble, and link steps.

In summary, the type of the input file determines where you start in the preprocess-compile-assemble-link sequence, and the `-c`/`-S`/`-E` options determine where you stop (they request output files of type `*.o`, `*.s`, and `*.i` respectively - although `-E` actually outputs to stdout by default).

Your command line has none of the output-type options, and its input file is named `*.c`, so it is a compile line *and* a link line. This is a normal way to compile small programs. With larger programs, you usually don't want to compile everything all at once. It's better to save the intermediate `*.o` files for reuse and only recompile them when their source file changes.

The "recompile as needed" development cycle involves `gcc -c` commands to create the `*.o` files, usually one at a time, and a `gcc *.o -o theprogram` command to do the linking. These commands are commonly found in a Makefile and are referred to as "compile lines" and "link lines".